# Delphi: Moving away from VSS

Tags: delphi, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

We are team of few Delphi developers who have been using VSS since years (I know it's a pity), but we don't use any of the advanced features of VCS, so it was working fine in many cases (but some times it was driving me crazy :( ).

The good thing that we have with  VSS that we use third-party plug-ins to integrate VSS with Delphi, which is working great, but now when our projects becomes larger, and we would like to move a way from VSS.

I have looked at few other VCS (free and commercial) and found most of them seems be made for Linux guys, and you have to use command line for many admin work(I know I'm windows guy :P).

What I'm looking for the new Version control that it should be easy to use and to maintain and Integrated nicely with Delphi IDE (D2007), or at least have a good UI for the Admins an developers.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just use [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) and an excellent [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) client which integrates with the Windows Explorer.

P.S. Found this question: [What is the best set of tools to develop Win32 Delphi applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63957/what-is-the-best-set-of-tools-to-develop-win32-delphi-applications) and this Delphi IDE/TortoiseSVN integration tools in one of the answers: http://delphiaddinfortortoisesvn.tigris.org/

Comment: I second that. Great combination.

Comment: Agreed, +1. If you're used to IDE-integration Tortoise might feel a bit cumbersome initially. I eventually noticed that it's far more flexible to be able to version-control anything I want instead of only things my IDE knows about.

Comment: No extra out of the box support in Delphi 2009 (there is no 2008), but there are several delphi addins that can do that.

Comment: I use svn, but I detest TortoiseSVN. The command line works fine. I combine it with Model Maker Structured Difference Viewer as my compare tool.

Comment: I have been playing with SVN and TSVN for few days, and I start to understand how it's works compared to VSS, but still few things need to have more explanation.

Comment: I really hate shell extensions, for several reasons. What SVN really lacks is a good GUI client. RapidSVN development pace is appaling, and other projects like eSVN are not better. Command line works, but when performing complex operations is more error prone than a good GUI. Why noone ever developed a decent GUI client for SVN is a mistery - it looks most developers are ok using basic functionalities only.

Comment: TortoiseSVN is shell extension, which is indeed convenient while doing development tasks with computer, but awful architecture while using shell as... shell, you know.

Answer (score 2):

You should at least take a look at [JVCS](http://jedivcs.sourceforge.net/).  It integrates with the Delphi IDE, it's written in Delphi and is open source, and you can choose from a number of databases including Firebird to store your archive in.

Answer (score 1):

There is Team Coherence (http://www.teamcoherence.com/) which is written in Delphi and integrates with the IDE very well. We still use it. Support is patchy though.

Most people seem to be moving to SubVersion though.

Comment: Team Coherence will be the very good option, but they have not release any major version since years. and support isn't good as I heard from many people.

Answer (score 1):

Team Coherence is a good choice.  They just released a new client, so it looks like support is alive and well.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are directly heading to SVN (which I wouldn't recommend, if you're thinking on something free go to Git or Mercurial) check Plastic SCM. Find a couple of Delphi specific tutorials here:

http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2008/06/branching-and-merging-with-delphi-part.html
http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2008/06/branching-and-merging-with-delphi-part_02.html

Answer (score 0):

Our Delphi team recently (last year ) upgraded from VSS to [Perforce](http://www.perforce.com) which is an absolute joy to work with.  It is expensive but is well worth it.  It makes source code control one of the tools of your trade rather than a chore or a hinderance.  It has good GUI tools, a great commandline when required and there is a free Delphi IDE integration available online.

It does take a bit of getting used to, but is worth putting in the effort when you get to the point where you can create branches with abandon and merge changes knowing you dont ever have to worry about losing any changes ever.  Its fast, efficient and a pleasure to use.

Comment: I have looked at Perforce few years ago, and I found it not easy in the administration site, you need to deal with command line tocreate a repository, I felt it's more for Linux people, I will take another look because the IDE Integration, Thanks

Comment: A small number of things need to be done from the command line, but most stuff can be done with a GUI.  I'm not a command line person but I put up with the few things I have to .